# ASP.NET MVC routing: how to use routing over matching files for a single folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a file on disk in the path /Files/filename.txt and the MVC routing system checks if the file exists before using its routing logic (with controller, action...).

I want to use routing logic before matching files on disk.

If I set "RouteExistingFiles=true" it will ALWAYS use routing over matching files. I want this behaviour only for a particular folder.

The "FilesController" must be called even if the file in Files folder exists. Basically I want the opposite behaviour of "IgnoreRoute()".

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to take a two part approach to this.

```
<system.webServer>
     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>

<location path="files">
     <system.web>
          <authorization>
               <deny users="*"/>
          </authorization>
     </system.web>
</location>
```

1. Make sure that your runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests in your web.config is true in order for the UrlAuthorizationModule to run for static files.
2. Your going to need to specifically stop asp.net from serving up the files in the folder named files.  You can do this by adding a location entry in to your web.config inside of the configuration node.  This is specifically telling the Authorization Module that no matter who the user is they do not have access to this folder.

After this has been done then your FilesController will now be in charge of serving the files up for the files folder.